# Cannot find or run integration test using VS Express 2012 for Web, MVC4, WatiN & NUnit

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, nunit, integration-testing, watin

I am trying to get the "Hello World" WatiN example working using VS Express 2012 for Web, MVC4, WatiN and NUnit.

However, the test does not seem to be recognised by Visual Studio. When I right click in the test method, and click "Run tests" nothing happens except the rebuild (which is clean). At no point does anything show up in the "Test explorer".

The integration test code is:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using NUnit.Framework;
using WatiN.Core;

namespace FootyStatMVC1.Tests
{
    [TestFixture]
    [RequiresSTA]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [Test]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {

            IE ie = new IE("http://www.google.com");
            ie.TextField(Find.ByName("q")).TypeText("WatiN");
            ie.Button(Find.ByValue("Google Search")).Click();

        }
    }
}
```

I have installed both NUnit and WatiN using nuget. I have also added the configuration code advised by

http://agilewarrior.wordpress.com/2010/07/02/getting-started-with-watin-nunit-and-mvc-net/

The resulting config file is called app.config and looks like this:

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
  </appSettings>
  <connectionStrings></connectionStrings>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>

  <!-- MSM integration testing aug 31st-->
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="NUnit">
      <section name="TestRunner" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler"/>
    </sectionGroup>

  </configSections>

  <NUnit>
    <TestRunner>
      <!-- Valid values are STA or MTA (Others are ignored) -->
      <add key="ApartmentState" value="STA" />
    </TestRunner>
  </NUnit>

</configuration>
```

Why is the test invisible to Visual studio?

Thanks in advance!

Mat

Comment: Update: I have noticed the following "i" (information) warnings in the error list for the build: "Could not find schema information for the element 'NUnit' " and similar warnings for 'TestRunner', 'add', 'key' and 'value'. All referring to lines between the <NUnit> tags. Why is VS not recognising these?

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio 2012 won't recognise NUnit unit test fixtures.  It uses its own Microsoft test framework, similar to NUnit, but not the same.

The Express version that you are using won't even recognise Microsoft tests, because a test runner is not included in the Express version.

Your best bet is to use the NUnit test runner outside of Visual Studio.

Sadly all other test runners that plug into Visual Studio 2012 won't work with Visual Studio 2012 Express because it also doesn't allow plug-ins.  If you wish to use one of the many integrated test runners within Visual Studio you will have to upgrade.